# Store contains only data inside "raw" property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm having strange problem with my store inside ExtJS. My ASP.NET MVC3 controller returns JSON:

[image]

My store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        // I know the model works
        model: 'MyApp.model.User',
        storeId: 'Users',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'users/read',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'users'
                // also tried this
                rootProperty: 'users'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now, when I connect this store to the grid inside `ExtJS 4.2.1`, the grid shows **TWO rows but without data**. When I `console.log(store)` I see the data only inside `raw property`, not inside `data property`.

Does anyone know what's the problem? Why isn't there any mapping? The grid's dataIndex is also the same as Models fields (I've done this a thousand times with PHP, I don't know where is the problem here.)

One more thing I've tried. I've tried `renderer: function(value) { console.log(value); }` inside grid's columns and I was just getting `undefined`.

Edit: this is how the JSON actually looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SENCHA what the hell?! Sencha Touch 2 always says put everything in `config`?
Now when I do that in ExtJS, everything breaks?

I removed everything from `config: {}` and now it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `root: 'users'` not `rootProperty`.  If not specified `root` defaults to `''`.

[Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader)

Comment: I think it is 'rootProperty' in Sencha Touch. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader

Comment: Thank you but still not working. It shows two again rows but without data.

Comment: I've found the solution. You can look at my answer. I'm giving you +1 for trying. :)